# проблема с прокси на seleniumwire python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, proxy

Писал парсер яндекс новостей на Selenium и мне пришлось использовать платные прокси с авторизацией. Установил библиотеку seleniumwire, передаю ей словарь с прокси, а в окне браузера вот это, что делать вообще ума не приложу.

```
        proxy_dict = {
            'proxy' : {
                'http' : f'http://{i}',
                'https' : f'https://{i}',
            }
        }
        try:
            print(proxy_dict)
            browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=optian, seleniumwire_options=proxy_dict)
            browser.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
                "source": """
                    const newProto = navigator.__proto__
                    delete newProto.webdriver
                    navigator.__proto__ = newProto
            """
            })
            browser.get(url)
            r = browser.page_source
            time.sleep(5)
            if 'Unfortunately, it looks like the search requests sent from your IP address are automated' in r or 'Please confirm that you and not a robot are sending requests' in r:
                print('Капча, продолжаю работу')
                time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
                browser.quit()
                continue
            browser.quit()
            return r
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Ошибка: {e}')
            browser.quit()
            print('Продолжаю работу...')
            time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
            continue
```

[image: Скриншот из браузера]

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте указать так:

```py
proxy_dict = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': f'http://{login}:{password}@{address}:{port}',
        'https': f'https://{login}:{password}@{address}:{port}',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=optian, seleniumwire_options=proxy_dict)
```

где:

- `login` - имя пользователя платного прокси;
- `password` - пароль;
- `address` - адрес (ip);
- `port` - порт

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили, но к сожалению не помогло( У меня есть функция, которая достает прокси из txt файла, где они записаны в таком же формате: login:password@ip:port

Comment: Строку проверьте, не осталось там завершающего символа перевода на новую строку, типа "login:password@ip:port/n"?